# Azure Access to Internal Selenium Server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, devops

We are currently testing out DevOps but one thing that I can't do is have MSTest hit our internal server (which is housed in Azure) that contains selenium and such.

DevOps of course is external.

I am no networking guru, but is there a way to build a connection between the two?

Or do we have to make our selenium server outward facing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup site-to-site vpn connection between your internal network and azure. Here is the documentation:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Comment: just to make sure...devops is not our server...I don't see any instructions on anything if I need to add any sort of information on the devops site..so all of this can be done on our selenium server? That is internal and of course resides on Azure...sorry I missed that part.

Comment: You are using Azure DevOps and run your Selenium setup in a Azure VNet? Or is DevOps something else? Either way most CI/CD support vpn access to another site so that you do not have to make anything public. Read the documentation or contact support. Seems a common feature.